# sorting name, surname, id alphabetical order with using only a singly linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKzGI.png)

I have a struct like the given below:

```
struct Student
{
    char *name;
    char *surname;
    long int ID;
    struct Student *name_next;
    struct Student *surname_next;
    struct Student *ID_next;
}
```

I need to sort according to alphabetical order of name and besides that alphabetical order of surname and also sort according to ID. But I can only use a single linked list, not three lists. How can I do that?

Comment: Your struct is poorly designed. Why not store just a Student struct node as next and that struct will have it's own  name, surname and id. No need to use 3 separate variables

Comment: I need to sort separatly name, surname and id. But I allowed to use only a single linked list.

Comment: Where is your student's data initially stored? An array? A file? Another linked list?

Comment: Okay, I get _why_ you might want to have _three_ `*_next` pointers. Probably better to have: `enum { BYNAME, BYSURNAME, BYID };` and `struct Student next[3];` and be indexed by one of the enum values. But, _can_ you just _resort_ the list as needed. Then, you only need _one_ `next` pointer. Please _edit_ your question and add some clarification.

Comment: I should add, this is a weird way to sort things, but using three extra pointers doesn't seem efficient